# Как поступить с translate?

Tags: jquery, css

Как можно при translate сдвинуть hidden элемент на его высоту ?
Пояснения, имеем блок со скрытым содержимым которое скроллится при hover на высоту 100% но если высота разная то и работает не так как ожидается !

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0:
}

.wrap {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.item {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 4px double #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
}

.item1 {
  transition: transform 2s linear;
  height: 100%;
}

.item1 img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.item:hover .item1 {
  transform: translate(0, -100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item1">
      <img src="https://s.tmimgcdn.com/scr/61300/easy-audit-multipage-consulting-website-template_61349-original.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item1">
      <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-E8DDnbyzgEk/UaCt9YSEqzI/AAAAAAAAABA/FCgblK-F4xY/s1600/THEYALOW-A-Responsive-Web.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Как можно исправить ситуацию ?**

Comment: если поставишь translate на img будет одинаково прокручиваться

Comment: @Grundy  тоже самое же : https://codepen.io/MaximLensky/pen/yzRxMK?editors=1100

Comment: нет не то же. Сейчас у тебя картинка **полностью** поднимается вверх, что в одном случае, что в другом. То есть действую **одинаково** - то что ты и хотел

Comment: @Grundy нее , надо что бы только до конца изображения поднималась а не на контролируемую высоту с белом полем в самом  низу

Comment: Про это и надо было писать в вопросе :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы получить данный эффект:

- добавляем `transition` на тэг `img`
- `transform: translate(0, calc(-100% + 250px));` на `.item:hover img` - для прокрутки при наведении на окно. Чтобы вычислить высоту на которую нужно переместить `img` используем `calc(-100% + 250px),` где `250px` - высота окна(`.item`)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0:
}

.wrap {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.item {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 4px double #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
}

.item1 {
  height: 100%;
}
img {
  transition: transform 2s linear;
} 
.item1 img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.item:hover img {
  transform: translate(0, calc(-100% + 250px));
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item1">
      <img src="https://s.tmimgcdn.com/scr/61300/easy-audit-multipage-consulting-website-template_61349-original.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item1">
      <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-E8DDnbyzgEk/UaCt9YSEqzI/AAAAAAAAABA/FCgblK-F4xY/s1600/THEYALOW-A-Responsive-Web.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: добавь описание, что именно ты сделал и почему

Answer (score 1):

100% в строке `transform: translate(0, -100%);` применяется берется от высоты **конкретного** элемента.

В данном случае это элемент с классом `item1`. По стилям его высота `height: 100%;` - 100% от высоты контейнера, которым является элемент с классом `item`. У этого элемента задана точная высота: `250px` - именно эта высота будет и у нужного элемента и именно на эту высоту всегда прокручивается содержимое.

Для решения проблемы нужно сделать два шага:

1. Убрать `height:100%`, чтобы высота блока растягивалась по содержимому
2. Чтобы прокрутка заканчивалась на нижней границе, а не на верхней, нужно из 100% вычесть высоту контейнера, которая в данном случае - 250px

В итоге все может выглядеть так:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0:
}

.wrap {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.item {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 4px double #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
}

.item1 {
  transition: transform 2s linear;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.item1 img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.item:hover .item1 {
  transform: translate(0, calc(-100% + 250px));
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item1">
      <img src="https://s.tmimgcdn.com/scr/61300/easy-audit-multipage-consulting-website-template_61349-original.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item1">
      <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-E8DDnbyzgEk/UaCt9YSEqzI/AAAAAAAAABA/FCgblK-F4xY/s1600/THEYALOW-A-Responsive-Web.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: да точно... до меня только дошло ... отнять высоту родителя при смещение ...

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, обрати внимание, что в коде стоит `-100% + 250`, то есть по сути мы _прибавляем_, но это всего лишь другая запись для `- (100% - 250px)`

Comment: до меня дошло когда я увидел изменённый calc , it's indescribable happiness fully own css